# Can't use Newtonsoft.Json in my project with Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, json, windows, visual-studio-code, json.net

I followed several tutorials to add Newtonsoft.Json in my project by doing the following :

> dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json

Here is the terminal log :

```
info: Added PackageReference for package 'Newtonsoft.Json' in project 'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio Code\[...]'
info: Restoring packages for 'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio Code\[...]'
info: CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/index.json
info: The 'Newtonsoft.Json' package is compatible with all frameworks specified in the 'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio Code\[...].csproj' project.
info: PackageReference for package 'Newtonsoft.Json' version '13.0.1' added to file 'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio Code\[...].csproj'.
info: Validation of the restoration...
info: Writing component file to disk. Path: C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio Code\[...]\obj\project.assets.json
log: Restore completed in 277.34 ms for C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio Code\[...].csproj.
```

After executing the command, here is the content of my project .csproj file :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Then I add:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

The problem is that Visual Studio Code doesn't offer me Newtonsoft.Json when I start writing it with **using**.

Is there something I need to do on my part?

Comment: Is it just that Intellisense does not offer it, or does it produce an error when you enter in manually? Also: do you target .NET Core 3.1 by purpose or was this by accident?